# Set PORT still first tries to run on 3000 React App

Tags: reactjs, npm, ssh, pm2

I have two react apps that I am trying to run using pm2. One app is running fine on port 3000. When I try to run second app, it fails to run.

I have specified port number in package.json file i.e 3001, still it gives a message that some other program might be using port 3000, do you want to run your app on another port? If I press Y, it starts running fine on 3001, but with pm2, I think we can't have this option to get a response this way.

Can Anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

How have you specified the port number in `package.json`?

```json
"start": "export PORT=3001 react-scripts start"
```

Have you tried using [cross-env](https://github.com/kentcdodds/cross-env) package?